# Rails 4 Nested Form not Linking Child to Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parent-child, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am trying to make a nested form between classes Participant and GroupParticipant.  However, when I submit the form only the Participant is saved in the system.  Below are the relevant parts of models, controller, view, and output:

participant.rb

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relationships
   has_many :group_participants#, inverse_of: :participant
   has_many :groups, through: :group_participants
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_participants
```

group_participant.rb

```
class GroupParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
#relationships
belongs_to :participant#, inverse_of: :group_participant
belongs_to :group
```

participant_controller.rb

```
class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_participant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @participant = Participant.new
    @participant.group_participants.build
  end

  def create
    @participant = Participant.new(participant_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @participant.save
        format.html { redirect_to @participant, notice: 'Participant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @participant }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @participant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def participant_params
    params.require(:participant).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :nickname, :female, :notes, :date_of_birth, :grade, :role, :active, :size,
    group_participants_attributes: [:id, :group_id, :participant_id, :active, :year])
  end
```

I am using simple_form and nested_form for views
participants/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @participant do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :role, label: "Role", collection: Participant::ROLES %>
  <%= f.input :first_name, label: 'First Name' %>
  <%= f.input :last_name, label: 'Last Name' %>
  <%= f.input :female, label: 'Gender', collection: Participant::FEMALE, required: true  %>

  <%= f.fields_for :group_participants do |gp| %>
    <%= gp.text_field :group_id %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
 <% end %>
```

When I submit the form, only the Participant is created, and not the GroupParticipant.  I had seen examples where the child objects are created automatically with correct foreign_id, but When looking at the rails server output I see that the participant_id is not included in the GroupParticipant params:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...",
             "participant"=>{"role"=>"child", "first_name"=>"Bob", "last_name"=>"Belcher", "female"=>"false",
             "group_participants_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"group_id"=>"1"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Participant"}
```

Upon submitting the form, the server also outputs the SQL only for creating a participant:

```
  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)
    INSERT INTO "participants" ("created_at", "female", "first_name", "last_name", "role", "updated_at")
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [ ["created_at", "2015-03-04 19:57:07.674319"], ["female", "f"], ["first_name", "Bob"], ["last_name", "Belcher"], ["role", "child"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-04 19:57:07.674319"]]
  (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

I have tried everything to get it to work like this, but I can't get it to work.  I suspect it has something to do with the build calls in the controller, but I have tried tinkering with that to no avail.  Also tried adding the "inverse_of" property to the models.

If anyone has any insight to my problem, including a reference to a working example on Rails4, I'd be grateful.  At this point, I'm also willing to hack together something in the controller, like saving the parent first then passing its id to the child, but as for now I can not figure this out.

Comment: Did you get my point? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think changing this will solve your problem:

`ParticipantsController`

```
def create
    @participant = Participant.new(participant_params)
    ...
    ...
end
```

Comment: thanks for responding.  I tried but it still only created the participant.

Comment: So what does it say in console ? GroupParticipant.count?

Comment: I can see in both rails console and the browser that no GroupParticipant records are created.  I edited my above question to include the SQL output when I submit the form, and you can see there is no insert to the GroupParticipant table.

Comment: could you try `raise participant_params.inspect` in `create` action?

Comment: I get the same Parameters as listed above in the ":participant => {...}" block